# Strange behavior of LibSVM

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm

I often test my classifiers by classifying two identical normals (or to be more precise: two datasamples drawn from the same underlying distribution) or two normals which are clearly separable. However it seems that when using very simple LibSVM code and the rbf kernel, the result is a very high classification accuracy even when trying to classify two nearly identical normals:

```
clear all; close all; clc


gamma = 100;

% dummy data    

a = 15;
b = 50;

x = zeros(200,2);

x(1:100,1) = a.*randn(100,1) + b;
x(101:200,1) = a.*randn(100,1) + b;

% labels    

y(1:100,1) = 1;
y(101:200) = 2;


% Libsvm options
% -s 0 : classification
% -t 2 : RBF kernel
% -g : gamma in the RBF kernel

model = svmtrain(y, x, sprintf('-s 0 -t 2 -g %g', gamma));

% Display training accuracy
[predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values] = svmpredict(y, x, model);
```

Why is that? With Matlab's svmtrain I get chance level accuracy (around 50%), no matter which kernel I use. Furthermore LibSVM gives me extremly different results for my own dataset, and also very high accuracies even when I swap the labels of my dataset randomly..

Thanks

Comment: you should get very high accuracy of training with rbf kernel. All you need is high enough C and gamma and you can overfit any dataset (even, if data points come from **the same distribution**, as the probability of actually drawing to identical ones is 0 for continuous distribution).

Comment: Thank you, you were actually right, setting gamma and C to default gave me for the same data for LIBSVM as well accuracies of around 50%..hence it was a case of overfitting. However I still have a similar problem with my own data: Matlab's default SVM gives me an accuracy of 100% for linear classification and of 50% for polynomial or rbf, while Libsvm gives me an accuracy of 100% no matter which kernel - and I am using the same parameter settings for both toolboxes..how can that be?

Comment: You are using the same or default for both? Each toolbox has different defaults.

Comment: They also have some default preprocessing, which effifently alters meaning of hyperparameters

Comment: I actually set C (called "Boxconstraint" in MATLAB) to 0.2 for both (I think the default for C is 1 for both). I had not set gamma previously, but now I set it to 0.5 for Libsvm, and if I understand it correctly 0.5 is also the default value for MATLAB's own SVM. Now indeed I get 100% accuracy for the linear kernel, and around 50% for the rbf in both cases :-):-) However, the polynomial (degree not set, and should be default = 3 for both toolboxes) gives me 100% in Libsvm and around 50% in MATLAB's toolbox..?

Comment: Polynomial has more params than a degree. There is a scale and bias too

Comment: So basically for the polynomial kernel I was using: model = svmtrain(y, x, sprintf('-s 0 -t 1 -c 0.2 -g 0.5')) for LIBSVM and svmModel = svmtrain(feature(trainIdx,:), class(trainIdx), 'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'BoxConstraint',0.2, 'Kernel_Function','polynomial') for the default toolbox. Do you mean g and C again with bias and scale? As you see these should be identical..or do you mean something else?